# workflow Visual Studio 2013 2 does not appear httpSend

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I´m developing the following tutorial: How to create a custom activity in 
Workflow Manager 1.0 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn175762(v=azure.10).aspx in the section where it says drag a httpSend, this did not appear in the Toolbox.

[image]
send control doesn´t have method GET, and ResponseContent

Any help??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workflow Manager tools is not yet supported on Visual Studio 2013. We are still required to use Visual Studio 2012 to develop workflows for the Workflow Manager.

Edit : Seems like Microsoft has finally updated the description of the completed sample code to say that you need to stick with Visual Studio 2012 for WFM development. "WFM workflow authoring using WFM tools in VS 2013 is not supported at this time"
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Workflow-Manager-10-4d6b3c14